# Center fullscreen video div vertically without using flex

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a video that I want to overlay custom buttons and retain their positioning in full screen as well.

The following code works with one problem (the fullscreen div is not centered but positioned on top of the screen).

If I add `display: flex;` the fullscreen div is centered correctly but the buttons are now placed incorrectly.

**How do I get the buttons retain their position and the fullscreen item to display in the center?**

I'm inexperienced with CSS so any other errors I have made are worth pointing out to.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');

const player = main.querySelector('.player');

const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');


// Use fullscreen video button
function toggleFullscreen() {
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    closeFullscreen();
  } else {
    openFullscreen();
  }
}

/* View in fullscreen */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (main.requestFullscreen) {
    main.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (main.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    main.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (main.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    main.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

/* Close fullscreen */
function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}

// toggle play/pause
function togglePlay() {
  const method = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
  video[method]();
}
```

```css
.main {
  /*display: flex;*/
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.player {
  /*display: flex;*/
  max-width: 1920px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.viewer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 6%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.buttons>* {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn-fs {
  right: 10%;
}

.btn-play {
  left: 10%;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="player">
      <video class="viewer">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="btn-fs"><button onclick="toggleFullscreen()">Fullscreen</button></div>
        <div class="btn-play"><button onclick="togglePlay()">Play</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your `.player` class:

```
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Here's a working example:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');

const player = main.querySelector('.player');

const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');


// Use fullscreen video button
function toggleFullscreen() {
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    closeFullscreen();
  } else {
    openFullscreen();
  }
}

/* View in fullscreen */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (main.requestFullscreen) {
    main.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (main.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    main.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (main.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    main.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

/* Close fullscreen */
function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}

// toggle play/pause
function togglePlay() {
  const method = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
  video[method]();
}
```

```css
.main {
  /*display: flex;*/
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.player {
  /*display: flex;*/
  max-width: 1920px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.viewer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 6%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.buttons>* {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn-fs {
  right: 10%;
}

.btn-play {
  left: 10%;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="player">
      <video class="viewer">
          <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="btn-fs"><button onclick="toggleFullscreen()">Fullscreen</button></div>
        <div class="btn-play"><button onclick="togglePlay()">Play</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```